# Proper Procedures for Regrading Under a Deck?

Tags: deck, drainage, gravel

We have been getting tons of water in our basement during downpours (not regular rainfalls). The water comes in where the deck is located. I ripped up some deck boards and found the soil underneath basically in a mound, where all the water drained towards the foundation, especially so where the water was coming in.

I am going to regrade the soil, but what do I have to do after this? I am toying between landscape fabric or plastic on top of the regraded soil, then cleaned 3/4" crushed stones on top of that to keep it in place. Is this the proper procedure? Is it better to use landscape fabric instead of plastic? I want to make sure my regrading does not erode away over time. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Do you have gutters installed? If so, do the downspouts need to be redirected? Can you repair the walls or floor in your basement where the water's entering?

Comment: We do have gutters installed over the deck and redirected downspouts, luckily. Unfortunately, I don't have access to where the water is actually entering the house. It enters where the original foundation and the foundation from an addition meet. I ripped off the walls built around these areas but still don't see the water's entry point.

Outside, the soil level was at least 6 inches lower than every surrounding area, so whenever it rained, the water just funneled into that corner of the foundation. Maybe I could dig deeper and try putting some sort of sealant in that corner as well?

Answer (score 1):

Regrading the soil is a must since the soil level was 6" below the rest of the area. The landscape fabric keeps weeds out but not water so I wouldn't be using that. The plastic would have a limited life and you don't want to be ripping up deck planks to check it. I'd be thinking about installing flashing under the deck planks and sloping it down away from the foundation where you think the problem exists. You can get flashing in 50' rolls 20" wide at most home stores. Hope this helps a little. Good luck.

Comment: I have actually used fiberglass roofing similar to your advice. Tough to retrofit but moves the water further away but wide flashing may help.